# Timezone correct, UTC correct, time still wrong

Tags: date, timestamps, timezone, amazon-linux

I have an AWS EC2 server running Amazon Linux (like rhel fedora) which does not know how to tell time, or is somehow not accounting for Daylight Savings Time. This makes all of my timestamps off by 1 hour.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ date && date -u
Thu Oct 24 17:19:56 EST 2019
Thu Oct 24 22:19:56 UTC 2019
```

The problem with that output is that (at the time of the command), the actual time in EST was `18:19:56`.

Again, UTC time is correct, I've set my `/etc/localtime` link to `America/Detroit`, but it still gloms onto `UTC-5` and does not adjust an hour for DST.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ sudo hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux 2.23.2
Using /dev interface to clock.
Last drift adjustment done at 1571955488 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 1571955488 seconds after 1969
Hardware clock is on UTC time
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2019/10/24 22:23:43
Hw clock time : 2019/10/24 22:23:43 = 1571955823 seconds since 1969
Thu 24 Oct 2019 05:23:43 PM EST  -0.689737 seconds
```

All of my tzdata is up-to-date. No updates pending on yum.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ echo $TZ

[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Dec  8  2015 /etc/localtime -> 
/usr/share/zoneinfo/EST
```

I'm at a loss. Does anybody know what could be going on? Does Linux not adjust for DST?

Comment: `echo $TZ` please. Should be empty. And I think you're still on EDT rather than EST. It's strange your server is reporting the wrong label.

Comment: @roaima Yes it is empty.

Comment: `TZ=US/Eastern date` returns your correct local time, or the one that's wrongly an hour off?

Comment: That shows the correct time! Hmm...

Comment: Can you show us the output of `timedatectl`,  if you have it?

Comment: That command is not found. I think the *ctl command set comes with a later version of the standard Amazon Linux image.

Comment: If you change your localtime link to US/Eastern is the problem solved?

Comment: @roaima Wow yes that solved it! Weirdly I couldn't even find that one in `tzselect`, but manually made the symlink to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Eastern` and now `date` shows the correct time. I even tried rebooting the server to see if the change would be permanent and it is. Awesome! Slightly curious why the other zones didn't work.

Comment: I wonder whether you're expected to use `New_York` when on the East Coast. For the West Coast we use `Los_Angeles`.

Comment: I think `America/New_York` is the standard option. Naively, I had assumed all the "Eastern" zones were equivalent. It hadn't even occurred to me to try swapping them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend on my comment, in most cases you want to select a city which corresponds to your timezone. It is likely that you do not live in that city. In most cases, it will be one of the largest city of your state, country, or timezone.

For example, in California we use `Los_Angeles` (full name is `America/Los_Angeles`).

The plain timezones, such as EST will generally not include definitions for summer and winter times. It is viewed as a generic timezone. UTC is also such a generic timezone. It also happens to be the one computers used as their base time. It does not include any adjustments either (i.e. no leap seconds, no summer/winter changes, a straight forward time, in other words). All the other timezones are now clearly based on UTC.

For the US East Coast, I think you are expected to use `America/New_York`.

In the US, we have several specialized timezones for places where there is no summer/winter changes. For example, Arizona has never used such clock changes. It remains on the same clock all the time. It has its specific timezone definition: `America/Phenix`. <s>Alaska</s> Hawaii is another state where they do not change their clock between winter and summer.

Now, I'm pretty sure that in the old days we would just use one of EST, CST, MST, or PST as our computer timezone. That has changed because of all the *problems* with using such generic designations. If you look at the list of timezones, you'll notice that there are very many of them. And they often get updated as a country or another makes changes to their timezone information.

Comment: @JimL. Ah! Thanks. I made a correction.